# Laravel: eloquent orderBy hasOne relation column using with and whereHas

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model `Product` with a hasOne relationship method `getCompany()`.

```php
public function getCompany(){
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class, 'id', 'company_id');
}
```

I need to retrieve the `Product` collection sorted by `getCompany.rate`

My approach

```php
$products = Product::with('getCompanyName', 'getCompany')
    ->whereHas('getCompany', function ($query) {
        return $query->where('status_shop_id', '=', 2);
    })
    ->whereHas('getCompany', function ($query) {
        return $query->where('status', '=', 1);
    })
    ->where('name', 'Like', "%$text%")
    ->whereStatus(1)
    ->whereTypeId(1)
    ->orderBy('rate', 'desc')
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

Fails with :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'getCompany.rate' in 'order clause'

I've tried to sort it after collected

```
return $products->sortBy('getCompany.rate');
```

But this doesn't sort at all

Comment: Best use `join`s if you want to sort based on another table's column.

Comment: @user3532758 Can you show me?

Answer (score 2):

> Best use joins if you want to sort based on another table's column.

> @user3532758 Can you show me?

Try something like this:

```
DB::table('products') //can use Product::join(...) as well and can attach your relationships too, just make sure necessary ids are in the select statement
->join('companies', 'products.id', '=', 'companies.product_id')
->select('products.*', 'companies.name', 'companies.rate')
->orderBy('companies.rate', 'desc')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort based on the contents of the relationship, you have to do that [after the fact](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby). The relations are presented as objects within the main model, and are fetched separately, so you can't expect to do it at the database level.

There's also no need to repeat the `whereHas` twice; you can just put both conditions in the callback.

```php
$products = Product::with('getCompanyName', 'getCompany')
    ->whereHas('getCompany', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status_shop_id', '=', 2)->where('status', '=', 1);
    })
    ->where('name', 'Like', "%$text%")
    ->whereStatus(1)
    ->whereTypeId(1)
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
$sorted = $products->sortByDesc('getCompany.rate');
```

A simple test will show this works effectively:

```
$coll = collect([
    ["name" => "item 1", "relation" => ["size" => 23]],
    ["name" => "item 2", "relation" => ["size" => 16]],
    ["name" => "item 3", "relation" => ["size" => 15]],
    ["name" => "item 4", "relation" => ["size" => 42]],
]);
dump($coll->sortBy('relation.size'));
```

Output:

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#12167
     all: [
       2 => [
         "name" => "item 3",
         "relation" => [
           "size" => 15,
         ],
       ],
       1 => [
         "name" => "item 2",
         "relation" => [
           "size" => 16,
         ],
       ],
       0 => [
         "name" => "item 1",
         "relation" => [
           "size" => 23,
         ],
       ],
       3 => [
         "name" => "item 4",
         "relation" => [
           "size" => 42,
         ],
       ],
     ],
   }
```